# Can't install or remove anything anymore

Tags: apt, dpkg

I was following a tutorial on how to install Vulkan on Ubuntu, link [here](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers), but in the process ended up somehow messing with initramfs-tools. Everytime I try to remove or install anything either via `.deb` files or with the `apt` or `apt-get` commands, I get the following error:

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdc3
I: (UUID=444ddd94-292f-4da1-880e-ad84b5cfe089)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/vdfuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: For a long shot. can you show `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/` and `cat /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/vdfuse`

Comment: Would you please show all the commands you used. That may help someone who knows about this. There are several cases on the page you linked and so you could have been using any one of them. These commands will be in your history, so in your console you can use the arrow up to go back to those commands (or open your ~/.bash_history in an editor)

Comment: @AlexisWilke I ran all the commands from the Nvidia and AMD/Intel sections.

Comment: @nobody the files in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/` are 
amd64_microcode  cryptpassdev      intel_microcode  reiserfsprogs
brltty   cryptroot      kbd       resume
btrfs   cryptroot-unlock    klibc-utils      thermal
compcache  dmsetup      kmod       udev
console_setup  fixrtc       lvm2       vdfuse
cryptgnupg  framebuffer      mdadm       zz-busybox-initramfs
cryptkeyctl  framebuffer-nvidia  nbd       zz-dhclient
cryptopenct  fsck       ntfs_3g
cryptopensc  fuse       plymouth

Comment: And the contents of `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/vdfuse` are here: https://pastebin.com/XsgU7Q8V.

Comment: You should take the habit of editing your question with those answers. These are complement to your question that should be there rather than in the comments. You can then make a note in the comments saying you updated your question with the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first aid.

```
sudo mv /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/vdfuse $HOME
```

Moves file in your $HOME then run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

Identify the package

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/vdfuse
```

This will only work, when the package is installed with apt or dpkg. If so remove it with

```
sudo dpkg -P packagename
```

Comment: I didn't install vdfuse via apt or dpkg, but moving the directory did the trick anyway.

Comment: same ... removing the hooks (udev and fixrtc) did the trick